# Как установить route на http-сервере при websocket-соединении?

Tags: java, маршрутизация, vert.x

Суть вопроса: имеем http-сервер, реализованный на базе vert.x core,к нему прикручен websocket хендлер(для того,чтобы можно было использовать при связи с сервером вебсокетное соединение). Теперь я бы хотел докрутить рутер, который входит в пакет vert.x web и прописать несколько рутов.Однако, проблема в том, что по [документации](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/), хендлер для рута
работает с Http. Вот пример для рутера:

```
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route().handler(routingContext -> {
      HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain");
      response.end("Hello World from Vert.x-Web!");
    });
    server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, new Handler<AsyncResult<HttpServer>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(AsyncResult<HttpServer> event) {
                if(event.succeeded()) System.out.println("server started");
                else System.out.println("server error");
            }
        });
```

И websockethandler с отправкой сообщений:

```
server.websocketHandler(new Handler<ServerWebSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ServerWebSocket webs) {
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                System.out.println("Client's message: ");
                webs.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer event) {
                        System.out.println("Received data: " + event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
                        webs.writeFinalTextFrame("echo: "+event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));

                    }
                });
            }
    });

        server.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, "localhost", res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Server is now listening!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
            }
        });
```

Как мне закрепить вебсоккетхендлер на этом руте?

Answer (score 2):

Я допер. В данном случае на вебсокетное соединение эти руты прикрутить нельзя. в документации на вертекс кор, нашел вариант как иначе указать пути. теперь оно выглядит так:

```
server.websocketHandler(new Handler<ServerWebSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ServerWebSocket webs) {
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                if (webs.path().equals("/write")) {
                    webs.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(Buffer event) {
                            servweb.setEvent(event);
                            System.out.println("Received data: " + event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
                        }
                    });
                } else if (webs.path().equals("/read")) {
                   webs.writeFinalTextFrame("echo: " + servweb.getEvent().toString("ISO-8859-1"));
                }
            }
        });
```